# How to make (mulitple) image appear when clicking?

Tags: python, pygame, mouseevent

im trying to make it so when i click on the mouse an image will appear then when i click a 2nd then 3rd then 4th time, an image will appear, i want it to keep looping through the images.

i set Dimension to  `pygame.imgage` then in my main loop, i tried to add it to an `event.` but nothing seemed to work when i run the code. It displays everything i need, sound as well but no image when i click. How do i fix? sorry im new.

```
import pygame
import SpriteSheet

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 450
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH))
pygame.display.set_caption("Rick & Morty Clicks")

Rick_Garage = pygame.image.load('Garage_.jpeg')
PortalGun = pygame.image.load('PortalGun_.png')
Dimension = pygame.image.load('PDimension1.png')

Gunsound = pygame.mixer.Sound('PortalGunsound.mp3')

pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

PortalGun = pygame.transform.scale(PortalGun, (200, 200))

Sprite_Sheet_image = pygame.image.load('PortalSheet.png').convert_alpha()
sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet.SpriteSheet(Sprite_Sheet_image)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

animation_list = []
animation_steps = 90
last_update = pygame.time.get_ticks()
animation_cooldown = 30
frame = 0

for x in range(animation_steps):
    animation_list.append(sprite_sheet.get_image(x, 400, 400, BLACK))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            screen.blit(Dimension, (0, 0))
            Gunsound.play()

    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if current_time - last_update >= animation_cooldown:
        frame += 1
        last_update = current_time
        if frame >= len(animation_list):
            frame = 0

    # if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        # screen.blit(Dimension, (0, 0))

    # Blit the garage background
    screen.blit(Rick_Garage, (0, 0))

    screen.blit(animation_list[frame], (250, 0))

    # Get the mouse position
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    # Blit the PortalGun image at the mouse position
    screen.blit(PortalGun, pos)

    # Update the display
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The code is drawing `screen.blit(Dimension, (0, 0))` on mouse-press in the event handling block, but then two lines later, clears the screen with `screen.fill((0, 0, 0))`.  So the `Dimension` bitmap is never seen.